# Number of normals from (-2,2) for parabola $y^2-2y-2-1=0$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Number of normals drawn from $(-2,2)$ to parabola $y^2-2y-2-1=0$ is?

The answer given is 1. I don't understand how a parabola can be represented by this equation. Is there a way of bringing this to a standard form such as $y^2=4ax$ or $x^2=4ay$? The solution given says these two things: the equation $$ (y-1) = m(x+1) - 2am -m^3 $$ and that $a = 1/2$. I know that $ y = mx - 2am -m^3 $ is the standard equation for a normal to a parabola, but how did they get this one? Also, how is $a=1/2$?

Comment: Are you sure you have your equation correct?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean something like $y^2-2y-2x-1=0$?

Comment: Cuz right now, there is no $x$ dependence

Comment: @glowstonetrees I'm not very sure actually, this was the exact equation that was given but there could be a printing mistake. It may be as you said.

Comment: If you plot the graph of $y^2-2y-3=0$ in the $xy$-plane, you just get two horizontal lines which are the roots of this quadratic (namely $x=3$ and $x=-1$), so I would guess that there is indeed a printing mistake

Comment: @glowstonetrees ohhh ok, should I edit the question?

Comment: Does it mean normals parallel to an axis, because surely there can be an infinite number of normals for a continuous function?

Comment: @HenryLee I don't think so.. and the answer is that only one normal is possible since m has only 1 real value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parabola is shifted, off the origin, which is why you have $y \to (y-1)$ and $x \to (x+1)$ in your equation.  And once you complete the square, you can pretty quickly see all the parts including $a$:

$$\begin{align}
y^2-2y-2x-1&=0 \\
y^2-2y\color{red}{+1}-2x-1&=0\color{red}{+1} \\
(y-1)^2&=2x+2 \\ 
(y-1)^2&=2(x+1) \\
&=4\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)(x+1) \\
\end{align}$$